# Algorithm - how to get count of active session in time series?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-series

I have a table in which we maintain user's login and logout time. Now I want to display a table to admin with number of active users with times like :

00:00 - 250
00:15 - 225
00:30 - 240
00:45 - 190
01:00 - 240
....
..

What algorithm we should use?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the answer(s) here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerers and for other users of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Make list/array with pairs `(time; incr = +1 for login, -1 for logout)`

Sort list by time key

Make `ActiveCount = 0`

Traverse list, adding `incr` to `ActiveCount`.

Value of `ActiveCount` in every moment corresponds to the number of active users

```
  login: 0; logout: 4
  login: 2; logout: 6
  list 
   (0;1), (2;1), (4;-1), (6;-1)
 count 
 0   1     2       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the list of login-logout pairs for all the users and simply put the user (or increment the count for that user) in appropriate bucket. Now if a particular user spans over multiple buckets, you'll have to consider putting that user (or increment the count for that user) in multiple buckets.

That's all about the algorithm. Probably the simplest one.

If you want to go in the implementation detail, you can use a `HashMap` or `unordered_map` whose keys will be your time at which you want to report the number of users and the value will start from zero, you will increment this value each time when you get a new user.